# Exporting glb file with webp images not working?

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I'm trying to export a glb file with webp images, now that webp images are supported. But for some reason the images aren't being bundled into the glb file.
Under Material in the export settings, I've made sure to set it to "Export", and then "Webp Format".

I have a bunch of webp images on my model, and I can see them working great in Blender.

I've tried replacing my webp images with jpeg and exported that. That works perfectly, so webp seems to be the problem.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Just because Blender is able to use them, that doesn't mean other software or the file format supports them...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues, it seems like the WebP exporter needs to have all images be the same type before converting or else it throws errors. I.e. they should all be jpeg or all be PNG. Also, I've found that images about 8K throw errors as well.